# For a subset $A$ of a metric space which of the following implies the other three ?

Tags: general-topology

For a subset  $A$ of  a metric space  which of the following  implies the other  three ?

$a)$ $A$ is closed

$b)$ $A$ is bounded

$c)$Closure  of $B$ is compact ,for  every $B \subseteq A$

$d)$ $A$ is  compact

I thinks  option d)  will correct  .

is it true??

Comment: Yes, it's true. (d) is the strongest condition you can have among them, (d) implies all the other.

Comment: @John_Wick thanks u

Comment: Obviously If $A$ is compact then it implies $A$ is closed and bounded then there is a subset  B whose closure is compact in fact any closed closed subset of a compact set in a (metric) space X is compact.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(d) is right, as a compact set is closed and bounded in any metric space.
and also if $A$ is compact then for $B \subseteq A$, $\overline{B}$ is closed in $\overline{A}=A$ and hence compact too.